# useColorScheme() always returns light on Android

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-go

I added `"userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"` in app.json file but it didn't help,  useColorScheme() always returns light on Android.

App.json

```
    {
    "expo": {
        "name": "AdamCoffee-Frontend",
        "slug": "AdamCoffee-Frontend",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "updates": {
            "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
        "ios": {
            "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
        },
        "android": {
            "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
        }
    }
}
```

App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
const [loaded] = useFonts(FontFamilies);
const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
console.log(colorScheme);
if (!loaded) {
    return null;
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
return (
    <DismissKeyboard>
        <View style={styles(colorScheme).container}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Loading">
                    <Stack.Screen
                        name="Loading"
                        component={LoadingPage}
                        options={{ headerShown: false }}
                    />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
            <FlashMessage position="top" duration={10000} />
        </View>
    </DismissKeyboard>
);
};

const styles = (mode: any) =>
    StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.getColor('backGroundColor', mode),
        },
    });

export default App;
```